# Add Sharepoint calculated field using AddfieldasXML - key cannot be null

Tags: sharepoint-server, error, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, addfieldasxml

I am trying to add a calculated field using the AddFieldAsXML method. And below is how I constructed the field xml.

```
> fieldXML ="<Field ID=\"{ABB544B1-5433-4B49-A629-7B242D3548E5}\"
> DisplayName=\"Test_field\"  ResultType=\"Text\" Name=\"testfield\">" +
> "<Formula>=CONCATENATE(column1,\"_\",column2)</Formula>"
>                 + "<FieldRefs>"
>                 + "<FieldRef Name=\"column1\" />"
>                 + "<FieldRef Name=\"column2\" />"
>                 + "</FieldRefs>"
>                 + "</Field>";
```

When I am trying to add it, I am getting an exception "Key cannot be null".

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If there is a space in the display name of your columns then make sure to use `[]` around column names.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing `Type` of the Field Element. Add below to Field element in XML:

```
Type="Calculated"
```

**Reference**: [Field element (Field)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/field-element-field).

Comment: Hi, does this answers your question? If yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you.